# The exact value of $\cot\frac{7\pi}{6}$?

Tags: trigonometry

I am working on a trigonometry question at the moment and am very stuck. I have looked through all the tips to solving it and I cant seem to come up with the right answer. The problem is

> What is exact value of
>   $$\cot \left(\frac{7\pi}{6}\right)? $$

Comment: $\cos(7\pi)/6$ or $\cos(7\pi/6)$?

Comment: Draw the reference triangle. Read off the value ($\pi/6$ is $30^\circ$, you have a "special triangle").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\cot \left(\frac{7\pi}{6}\right) = \cot \left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) = \sqrt 3 $$

because $$ \tan ( \theta + \pi) = \tan ( \theta ) $$

Answer (score 6):

We have $$\cot \left(\frac{7\pi}{6}\right) = \frac{1}{\tan \left(\frac{7\pi}{6}\right)} = \frac{\cos \left(\frac{7\pi}{6}\right)}{\sin \left(\frac{7\pi}{6}\right)} \equiv \frac{-\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}{-\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)} = \sqrt{3}$$

You can easily see this using a "CAST" diagram to reduce $\cos \left(\frac{7\pi}{6}\right)$and $\sin \left(\frac{7\pi}{6}\right)$ to standard results.

---

As per @Scientifica's comment, an easier method would be to simply note that $\tan$ is $\pi$-periodic so that shifting its argument by $\pi$ will yield no change to it's value, or: $$\cot \left(\frac{7\pi}{6}\right) = \frac{1}{\tan \left(\frac{7\pi}{6}\right)} = \frac{1}{\tan \left(\frac{7\pi}{6} - \pi\right)} = \frac{1}{\tan \left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)} = \sqrt{3}$$

Comment: I didn't downvote. In fact I gave you +1. I comment to tell you that it is easier using the fact that $\tan$ is a $\pi$-periodic function (which the OP itself used but confused $\tan$ and $\cot$)

Comment: @Scientifica, thanks for that. I included your method (which was the one I originally thought of but for some reason didn't work out in my head), I credited you as well. :-)

Comment: Thank you you too for being comprehensive and it's ok wether you credit me or not. It happens to me too that I think of something but then get the impression that it won't work hhh. One last remark: you forgot $\tan$ in $\tan\left( \frac{7\pi}{6}-\pi\right)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\cot x=\dfrac{\cos x}{\sin x}$ and

$$
\cos \left(\dfrac{7  \pi}{6}\right)=\cos \left(\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{6}\right)
$$

$$
\sin \left(\dfrac{7  \pi}{6}\right)=\sin \left(\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{6}\right)
$$

now you can use sum formulas or reduction to the first quadrant.